# Javascript function using `locatin.href = ...` works when called from console, not when called from `onClick` in a button

Tags: javascript, html

I imagine I'm missing something simple here, but I am kind of baffled.

I'm using Firefox Aurora 28.0a2

I have a button,

```
<button class="submit_button" id="search_google" onClick="search('google');">Google</button>
```

and, in a linked js file, the function

```
function search(siteName) {
    location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

(Naturally, this is only some test code, and I only expect it to open the google.com.) Now, when I click on the button, it doesn't load the url as expected. However, the button *is* calling the function successfully, since it'll trigger an alert if I add `alert("something")` to the function.

However, when I simply call the function from the console, it works exactly as expected.  What I find even more baffling is that, if I change the button to an anchor, it works *fine* when clicked.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: must be `window.location = ...`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with google chrome.
try add `top.` at the begining.

`top.location.href = "http://www.google.com";`

Comment: I thought I'd replied the day you posted this. Sorry for the delay! I tried adding `top.`, but to no avail.